# When using Laravel I can't get an ajax call to pass data to a class method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm very new to Laravel.

I would like to pass two variables from an ajax call to a method within a class.

My ajax call (derived from various Google searches) is:

```
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var inputValue = "Testing";
    var anotherInput = "Testing2";
    var data = {};
    data.anotherInput = anotherInput;
    data.inputValue = inputValue;
    data._method = 'POST';
    data._token = token;

            //data: JSON.stringify(data),
        $.ajax({
            url: postUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            processData: false,
            success:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }

        });
```

The var "postUrl" is set in my layout.blade.php here:

```
    <script>
      var postUrl = "{{ route('filepathtest') }}";
    </script>
```

The top of my Controller Class is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 // use Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Models\MainSettings;
use App\Http\Requests\MainSettingsRequest;




class MainSettingsController extends Controller
{
    private string $messageTitle = "";
    private $messageText = array();

    /**
     * Corrects path and checks it points to something.
     */
    public function filePathTest(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();    
        $response = array(
          'msg' => $data,
        );
        return response()->json($response); 
 
    }
```

And, finally, my route is:

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'filepathtest', [MainSettingsController::class, 'filePathTest'])->name('filepathtest');
```

My response gets logged to Console.Log and I see this:

[image]

I've tried lots of ways of accessing the variables from the Controller but to no avail?
I've tried:

```
$data = $request->input('anotherInput');
```

And:

```
$data = $request->anotherInput;
```

And:

```
$data = $request['anotherInput'];
```

And:

```
$data = $request->post('anotherInput');
```

And:

```
$data = $request->request('anotherInput');
```

But they all seem to return null apart from the last one gives me an error (unless I just "use Request;" at the top instead of "use Illuminate\Http\Request;") ?

Comment: Are you looking for `$request->input('anotherInput')` or `$request->anotherInput` (and same for `inputValue`? Your question is a little unclear on what the actual problem is, but your `POST` request looks good, your `return response()->json($response)` shows that the data you're passing it making it to the Controller, so what, **specifically** is the issue here? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75548646/edit) with more details, including an actual question 

Comment: Sidenote, `var data = {};` followed by `data.whatever` a bunch of times is kinda silly; just do `var data = { anotherInput, inputValue, '_method': 'POST', '_token': token }`

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, but is still a little odd... If `$request->all()` is returning `['anotherInput' => 'Testing2', ...]` (confirmed by your `response()->json()` return, then `$request->input('anotherInput')` or the shorthand `$request->anotherInput` should return `'Testing2'` (`$request['anotherInput']` is valid too, but isn't used as often)... Add some logging, like `\Log::info($request->all());`, and `\Log::info($request->input('anotherInput');` and check what is output to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Also, the correct `use` statement for this is `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Also, since this accepts a `GET` request too, you can try direct navigation, i.e. `http://localhost:8000/filepathtest?anotherInput=Testing2`; `$request->input('anotherInput')` should return `'Testing2'` there as well.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for the advice - the log shows:  [2023-02-23 18:23:35] local.INFO: array ( '{"anotherInput":"Testing2","inputValue":"Testing","_method":"POST","_token":"9YJSEaPKImdbMcemtFAs4nU0hec96bOsUB44bbuD"}' => NULL,
)  
It looks like the whole of the data is being used as the key for the array? Unless I'm mis-reading that? The Log of the individual variable was just blank?

Comment: @TimLewis I've just tried your Get link and that works? The variable gets logged correctly.

Comment: Oh of course; that makes sense, you're converting it to a single string: `data: JSON.stringify(data)`; just remove that `JSON.stringify`, and do `data: data`. Also explains why the `GET` one worked  Apologies, I completely glossed over that spot in the code (and the `console.log()` obfuscates that a bit too )

Comment: @TimLewis if I just send the data (without JSON.stringify) then I just get null coming through the Request $request it looks like? This was what I had originally but I'd found the JSON.stringify addition on Google. Thanks.

Comment: Probably need to also remove `dataType: 'json',`, or maybe `processData`? I'm not super familiar with that 2nd one though, but my local ajax request doesn't include them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/buqDo.png (this is a PATCH, but should be the same)

Comment: It's just the same with that removed - I just get an empty array on $data in that method?

Comment: Yeah, so looking at all my `$.ajax()` requests, they all have `$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: postUrl, data: postData })`; I don't use `dataType`, `contentType`, `processData`, or even `headers` (since `postData` includes the CSRF token). If you condense your request to the same minimum, does it work?

Comment: YES!! That's it!! It's working now.... how strange?? Do you want to add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you so much for your help. I was completely bamboozled.

Comment: It was the "processData: false" that was messing it up. I've just re-added it to test what was causing the issue. Can't thank you enough :-)

Comment: You're quite welcome  I always forget about those other AJAX settings, simply due to Laravel not requiring them in many situations, but this was definitely a good reminder lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this seems to be a combination of factors of your `$.ajax()` request. At a minimum, this should work for `POST` requests:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', // or 'PATCH', 'DELETE', etc.
  url: postUrl, // Any valid URL from your Laravel Routes or other external URL
  data: postData // Any plain JS object, or `FormData`, etc.
  // ...
});
```

In this case, there were a few issues:

1. `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

In this case, you were encoding your `data` object as a single String, and sending that to the controller. `$request->all()` was using that JSON string as an Array index, hence the weird `['{"anotherInput":"Testing2", ...}' => null]` output when logging via `\Log::info($request->all());`

This should simply be `data: data`, or even just `data` using JS object shorthand.

2. `processData: false`

I'm not familiar with this setting, but you can review the `$.ajax()` documentation to see when it is appropriate to use this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

3. `dataType`, `contentType` and `headers`

There wasn't anything wrong here per-se, but review if these are actually needed when making the `AJAX` request. If the `_input` key is included in your data, you can probably omit `headers`, but I doubt it would hurt to send it twice.

So, all in all, your code should function when refactored to:

```js
$.ajax({
  data: {
    inputValue: 'Testing',
    anotherInput: 'Testing2',
    '_method': 'POST',
    '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: postUrl,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

On the backend, `$request->all()` should return an array with 4 indices based on the data sent, and `$request->input(...)` should return the value of any of those indices, or `null` if specifying an invalid index.